# Why does Firefox display example1.foo when it should be displaying example2.foo?

Tags: firefox

I've setup Apache do create some virtual hosts.  Specifically, I've added the following to my httpd.conf:

`NameVirtualHost *:80`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example1.foo
    DocumentRoot /www/example1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example2.foo
    DocumentRoot /www/example2
</VirtualHost>
```

This was working fine in Firefox, but I was messing with it the other day to add a third virtual host and now example2.foo for some reason gets me the content of example1.foo.  If I go to example2.foo/includes/main.js, I do get the correct file, so there is something specifically wrong with the example2.foo/index.html.  If I try to hit example2.foo in Safari, which I never really use, then it works fine.

From this kind of experimenting, it would seem like Firefox is caching something, but I'm not sure what it's caching or how to flush it.  Anyone have any thoughts on this?  I have tried to clear private data in Firefox, clearing everything except cookies and saved passwords.

UPDATE: I restarted my computer, cleared the Firefox's cache again, and fiddled with the hosts file a little bit.  Doing all of these things resolved the problem and now we're good to go.  If someone knows why this happens, I'd be curious to hear an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It could be almost anything, in that 1) we don't know what experiments you did (did you ever trty the host by IP?) 2) we don't know the edit history on your httpd.conf (and did you remember to restart apache every time? and 3) we don't know how you're routing things to the server (real world DNS, your personal hosts file, or...)?

In such a situation, the general rule is to assume that everything caches stuff, everything in the cache(s) is wrong, and try again with a clean bench after any such change.

-- MarkusQ

Comment: maybe things are cached? it could be whatever as said above.